# Logbook: Machine Learning approaches

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms

In the past, when trying different machine learning algorithms in order to solve a problem, I used to write drown the set of approaches on a notebook, keeping details such as features, feature preprocessing, normalization, algorithms, algorithm parameters... therefore, building a hand-written logbook.

However, currently I'm concerned about using a 'more professional' tool, so that I can keep more details and even share it with other team-members, who are also able to stamp their approaches.

It would be great an automated and collaborative tool that keep track of the work done, considering details like: features, algorithms, algorithms parameter, data pre-process, data, metrics... beyond a collaborative Google Drive Spreadsheet for instance.

How are you solving this? How are you keeping track of the work done? What's your **logbook** tool?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How are you solving this? How are you keeping track of the work done?
>   What's your logbook tool?

This might not be the best approach. But, this is how my team does it. We believe that for pulling off an end-to-end data science experiment, proper conscience is very important. So, we use [Slack](https://slack.com/) for the same for our discussions and the meetings.

In addition to them, we have Rmd (R markdown) files for documenting the planning and the analysis parts.

Comment: I like the idea of using markdown, however, I guess it's not the best approach/solution. It's good for a starter point.
I also use Slack, and I highly recommend it for teams coordination and meetings.

Comment: @Jorge Yeah, I agree that it's not the best approach :)  However, I haven't found a good alternative worth spending on!

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](http://www.openml.org) out, looks like exactly what you need

Comment: Is this a Google product?  The UI looks very google-like

Comment: I don't know. I am not associated with that site in any way. They have their owners and hoster information listed on the front page though.

Answer (score 2):

> How are you solving this? How are you keeping track of the work done? What's your logbook tool?

For [my bachelors thesis](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.09030) ([write-math.com](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/classify/)) I wrote my own little toolkit to go through different models / preprocessing steps very fast. Each experiment had one configuration file (see [hwr-experiments repository](https://github.com/MartinThoma/hwr-experiments)). For example:

```
data-source: feature-files/baseline-3-points
training: '{{nntoolkit}} train --epochs 1000 --learning-rate 0.1 --momentum 0.1 --print-errors --hook=''!detl
    test {{testing}},err=testresult_%e.txt'' {{training}} {{validation}}
    {{testing}} < {{src_model}} > {{target_model}} 2>> {{target_model}}.log'
model:
    type: mlp
    topology: 24:500:369
```

The trained model is stored; it is pretty fast to get the evaluation results (e.g. accuracy, confuscation matrix).